# Property 'self.title' not initialized at super.init call in swift

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, uikit

I have a class derived from UIView , but i initialized it always show the error says "Property 'self.title' not initialized at super.init call in swift"

Here is my code

```
class A: UIView
{

var title : String
var recordUrl : String
var content : String

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

init(frame :  CGRect ,title : String, recordUrl : String  , content : String)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.title = title
    self.recordUrl = recordUrl
    self.content = content
}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
init(frame :  CGRect ,title : String, recordUrl : String  , content : String) {
    self.title = title
    self.recordUrl = recordUrl
    self.content = content
    super.init(frame: frame)
 }
```

In swift, you should init your parameter first, and then implement super.Method()

Comment: This doesn't work in swift 3.

Comment: @snapchatdotcom could you please tell, then what should we do in swift 3?

Comment: this works in swift 4. thanks! :)

Comment: This does not appear to work anymore. This throws an error like this: "self' used in property access 'title' before 'self.init' call"